# OnActionExecuting Loop MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

im using action filter to do one job in my project. I want to do that if user's ip equals to my ip, it will go to index without seeing a login page. If its ip is different i want to redirect him to login page. In login page i ask password and id. I have a problem with redirecting to login page. Here its my code, how can i fix this loop?

## FILTER

```
public class IntranetAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string LOCALIP = "192.168";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string ip1 = request.UserHostAddress;
        string shortLocalIP;
        if (ip1 != null && ip1.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] ipValues = ip1.Split('.');
            shortLocalIP = ipValues[0] + "." + ipValues[1];
        }
        else
        {
            shortLocalIP = "192.168";
        }

        //var ip2 = request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
        //var ip3 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_ADDR"];

        if (shortLocalIP != LOCALIP)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Login", //TODO - Edit as per you controller and action
                action = "User"
            }));

        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home", //TODO - Edit as per you controller and action
                action = "Index"
            }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

## Login Controller

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    // GET: Login
    [IntranetAction]
    public ActionResult User()
    {         
        return View();
    }


    public void checkAuthentication(UserLoginInfo loginInfo)
    {         
        bool isAuthenticated = new LdapServiceManager().isAuthenticated(loginInfo);
        if (isAuthenticated)
        {

            //HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("/", false);
        }         
    }
}
```

This loop in my filter class. shortLocalIP doesnt equal to my LOCALIP, it goes to my login page but it goes to inf loop

Comment: Remove the `[IntranetAction]` attribute from your `User()` method

Comment: But if i remove this attribute, my code doesnt work. It always redirects to my login page

Comment: Your attribute needs to be on all the other methods. What is currently happening is you go to the `User()` method which triggers the filter which redirects to the `User()` method which triggers the filter which redirects to the `User()` method which ........

Comment: You would need a different filter applied to the `User()` method which only redirects `shortLocalIP` equals `LOCALIP`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need another view `Index` in login controller.

If `user ip` and `your ip` are equal go to `Home/Index` otherwise go to `Login/Index`.

Your `startup` view will be `Login/User` where your `filter` will be placed.

```
public class IntranetAction : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string LOCALIP = "192.168";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string ip1 = request.UserHostAddress;
        string shortLocalIP;
        if (ip1 != null && ip1.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] ipValues = ip1.Split('.');
            shortLocalIP = ipValues[0] + "." + ipValues[1];
        }
        else
        {
            shortLocalIP = "192.168";
        }

        //var ip2 = request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
        //var ip3 = request.ServerVariables["SERVER_ADDR"];

        if (shortLocalIP != LOCALIP)
        {

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Login", //TODO - Edit as per you controller and action
                action = "Index"
            }));

        }
        else
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home", //TODO - Edit as per you controller and action
                action = "Index"
            }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, why should i use another one :( If i use second view, it will be the same as current one

Comment: No if you use another only those users will see it who's IP is different than you.,